# Is there a way to stop user from uninstalling your app or do something before that happens?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-permissions, uninstallation, parental-control

I am aware that many similar questions to that one were asked before, but I don't seem to be able to find anything that is recent(works). If I'm wrong, please direct me to a proper solution :).

With that being said - I am working on the app that is supposed to protect a child from visiting improper websites. The issue is - **kid can uninstall the app and go on its way**.

What I would like to have is - **preferably request for a password before uninstall** is allowed. If that's impossible(*which I can understand*), **it would be nice to at least have app shoot a message or some form of notification to the parents.**

I would prefer to avoid getting into Admin-device stuff, especially since it's getting deprecated, but if there is no other way, I would love to get some help about implementing EMM to achieve my goal as well.

If it's impossible any other way, would it be possible to install a companion app, that watches over the main one and reinstalls/shoots notification upon main app's uninstallation? Could I possibly loop them to each other so that when app A is uninstalled, app B installs it again and fires it up as well as the other way around?

**If nothing of what I would like is possible, is there anything similar I can do to at least let parents know about app getting uninstalled?**

Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you set your app as default launcher. Set a password for exiting launcher. If kids want to exit your launcher, they should enter a password.

Comment: That would be an excellent idea, but I'm unsure how that would work in my case. The app doesn't provide anything but background checking other sources, you don't use it to access the internet directly(if the kid would use chrome, for example, it will scan websites and redirect them to a blocking site), so you do need to exit the app to "use it".
Is there a way to use your solution in that case?

Comment: list all apps you want to kids have access in your launcher and then  launched them from this default launcher. you don't need to exit launcher

Comment: That might work great for me!
I never did a default launcher before, so if I will struggle I may come back and ask for a tip on that, but it sounds like a great idea, thank you a lot :).